# Problems validating archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture, app-store, arm64

Im trying to submit my finished app and send if off to the app store. I get an error everytime it comes to the validating process.

*"Invalid architecture: Apps that include app extension and framework must support arm64"*

Ive checked many times that all build settings in my parent app, extension app and frameworks are set to support arm64 and ive made sure that the app is ready for submission in itunes.connect

Anyone who have experienced same problem or can help?